# Get value for every date in table with date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with table, its structure looks like this:

- from_date `DATE %Y-%m-%d`
- to_date `DATE %Y-%m-%d`
- person `VARCHAR`
- tax `INT`

Table shows that in period between `date_from` and `date_to` for such `person` there was such `tax`

The whole point is that these periods can intersect and activities can sum. Roughly speaking, here is an example of a table:

| date_from | date_to | person | tax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-30 | 2020-02-02 | person1 | 20 |
| 2020-01-30 | 2020-01-31 | person1 | 10 |
| 2020-02-01 | 2020-02-03 | person1 | 15 |

And I need a table with structure:

- date `DATE %Y-%m-%d`
- person `VARCHAR`
- tax `INT`

where I get `tax` aggregated for every `date` for every `person` and it will be look like this

| date | person | tax |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-30 | person1 | 30 |
| 2020-01-31 | person1 | 30 |
| 2020-02-01 | person1 | 35 |
| 2020-02-02 | person1 | 35 |
| 2020-02-03 | person1 | 15 |

Hope I was able to explain in an understandable way what I want.

Below the code I tried. But recursive approach does not solve the problem because the table has about 5 millions rows

```sql
WITH cte AS (
 SELECT person, date_from, date_to, tax, date_from AS report_date
 FROM my_table
 WHERE date_from >= @date_from AND date_to < @date_to

 UNION ALL

 SELECT person, date_from, date_to, tax, DATEADD(DAY, 1, report_date) AS report_date
 FROM cte
 WHERE report_date < date_to
)

SELECT person, report_date, SUM(tax) tax
FROM cte
GROUP BY person, report_date
```

Comment: Create a calendar table, join, group by.

Comment: When you post data, please make sure that your data does make sense. `2020-02-31`

Comment: @Squirrel fixed the data, there should be `2020-01-31`

Comment: Create a list of dates containing dates from both from and to. Then do a running sum. If it was a start date then you add to the running sum else you subtract from it.

Comment: **The query you are showing is the best approach in my opinion.** The tax is meant to apply to every single day in a date range, so you create these days. This is an iterative process for which we use a recursive query in SQL.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, but there is the problem that the table is very large (about 5 million rows) and the recursive approach was not very suitable for this

Comment: I consider the recursive CTE quite suitable. A large table only means more processign time usually. But SQL Server may have limits there. I seem to recall something about a maximum depth causing issues. Salman A's idea might be a good alternative, though it needs some adjustments. Instead of creating the days per table row, you'd create all days and with these get running totals, because after all it's just day n = day n-1 + starters - enders.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner A tally table or tally function is almost certainly faster on a large set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a list of dates consisting of all start date, end date and end date + 1 in your table. Then calculate running sum such that:

- On start date the tax is added to sum
- On end date the tax remains unchanged
- On end date + 1 the tax is removed from sum

A group by is needed to compact rows having same date into one row.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT person, ca.*
    FROM t
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES
        (date_from, tax),
        (date_to, 0),
        (DATEADD(DAY, 1, date_to), -tax)
    ) AS ca(date, value)
)
SELECT person, date, SUM(SUM(value)) OVER (
    PARTITION BY person
    ORDER BY date
) AS tax_value
FROM cte
GROUP BY person, date
ORDER BY person, date
```

[And the result](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c19769410d24cb99f118ac92a8dd6958):

| person | date | tax_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| person1 | 2020-01-30 | 30 |
| person1 | 2020-01-31 | 30 |
| person1 | 2020-02-01 | 35 |
| person1 | 2020-02-02 | 35 |
| person1 | 2020-02-03 | 15 |
| person1 | 2020-02-04 | 0 |

Comment: Thank you, your code really helped a lot, but it still doesn't solve with my task.

I shared a simple example of a table, but in fact, my worktable has about 5 million rows, and in general it needs to be grouped by two semantic columns (`person` and, for example, `product`) and `date`.

In addition, the range of resulting dates can be limited to a period (`result_date BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date`)

Comment: Also in some lines the `tax` is doubled or has a negative value

Comment: It is trivial. Replace `person` in my query with `person, product` etc. The start and end date check could be added as a where clause inside cte but that would mean the query ignores tax on prior dates and starts counting from 0. For double or negative values I am sure there must be a reason. I hope all date start and date end are in correct order.

Comment: dates are shuffled, but `date_from <= date_to` for every row

Comment: [This code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7da1a58ef451857fe87b8a653462826f) I tested and it has issues I described in the comment above

Comment: The column names were messed up and in order to use where clause you needed an extra sub query - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e522483573d027b05d01f643c6c4259b

Answer (score 0):

emm, you can just group by from_date and person. like

```
select from_date, 
person,
sum(tax) as tax
from table
group by from_date, person
```

Answer (score 0):

May be not best solution. But below query should work

```
Declare @FromDate date,@ToDate date;

select @FromDate=min(date_from) from YourTable

select @ToDate=max(date_to) from YourTable

Create table #temp ([Date] date,person varchar(50), tax bigint)

WHILE (@FromDate <= @ToDate)
BEGIN

insert into #temp
select 
@FromDate,
person,
(select Sum(tax) from YourTable where @FromDate between date_from AND date_to)
from YourTable where @FromDate between date_from AND date_to

group by person


set @FromDate=DATEADD(DAY,1,@FromDate)

END


select * from #temp

drop table #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that doesn't create all days for all persons (i.e. several rows per row in the table). It merely creates all days, then aggregates the table twice, once to get the amounts that get added a day and once those that get subtracted. Then it's outer joining these sums to the days and get the running total.

This is based on Salman A's idea hence to work with a running total.

```
with days (day, max_day) as
(
  select min(date_from), max(date_to) from my_table
  union all
  select dateadd(day, 1, day), max_day from days
  where day < max_day
)
, starters (day, total) as
(
  select date_from, sum(tax) from my_table group by date_from
)
, enders (day, total) as
(
  select date_to, sum(tax) from my_table group by date_to
)
select
  days.day,
  sum(coalesce(starters.total, 0) - coalesce(enders.total, 0))
    over (order by days.day) as tax
from days
left join starters on starters.day = days.day
left join enders on dateadd(day, 1, enders.day) = days.day
order by days.day;
```

If you want to limit this to a date range then:

```
select *
from (above select)
where day >= @date_from and day < @date_to
order by day
```

Demo with slighty changed sample data to have date gaps in the data: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4d64c881b3026abb5f5ab23aa09fc259